# Capture event when keyboard appears in hybrid app Android

Tags: android, android-webview, android-softkeyboard

I need throw a callback to my Javascript code when the keyboard appear, the app have a webview with javascript and HTML.

Comment: I'm not putting this an an answer because I'm not very sure but try this and let's see what happens -> http://pastebin.com/9CsSU2DE

Comment: thanks bhowden, I tried that but did not work.